# At what age did Kakashi Hatake become a Jounin?

Tags: naruto

[This answer on Yahoo!](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110417182121AAgkRcz) says he became a Jounin at the age of 13, which makes him the youngest Jounin.

> I have heard a lot of chatter on the subject, but I've never seen the answer stated outright (or with any proof). The youngest I've seen reference to was Kakashi. He was a chunin at 6, a jonin at 10, and joined ANBU Black Ops at 13.
>
> Itachi, on the other hand, became a chunin at 10 and became a Captain of ANBU Black Ops at 13. He's still pretty amazing, but Kakashi was younger.
>
> Sources:
>
> - http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake
> - http://www.absoluteanime.com/naruto/itachi.htm

Is it true that he is the youngest Jounin? What is his real age when he became a Jounin?

[The magic number starts from at the age of 5](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake)

Comment: 13 is correct actually. In Naruto, not Naruto Shippuden, I remember vaguely that Kakashi was speaking with another Jounin and Kakashi made a comment about how he was already a Jounin at Naruto's age. Not posted as an answer purely because I am lazy to go and find that one episode out of like 220 in search of that one line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kakashi became a Genin at the age of 5 and Chunin at 6.

Obito became a Genin at the age of 9 and Chunin at the age of 11.

It was around the time when Obito became Chunin that Kakashi was promoted to Jonin.

Obito then "died" at the age of **13**, which was almost two years after his promotion to Chunin.

From [this thread on narutoforums](http://www.narutoforums.com/showthread.php?t=855357) (emphasis mine):

> It is impossible for both Kakashi and Obito to have been 13 during the Kakashi Gaiden, because there is at least a confirmed **4 year age difference** between Kakashi and Obito when they were confirmed to both be Genin teammates during the Chuunin Exams. They entered the academy the same time, and they all graduated the academy together as teammates. Kakashi was at least 4 years younger than both of his teammates at all times. There is **no** possible way that Kakashi was a 13 year old Jonin during the Kakashi Gaiden.
>
> At this idea that he was 13 isn't even supported in the databooks, either. It's time we all got our facts straight. If Obito died at 13, then Kakashi was most likely **9** during the Kakashi Gaiden. It is impossible for these two teammates to have ever been the same age.
>
> **Kakashi was 13 during the Kyuubi attack on Konoha**. There is a 4 year difference between the events of the Kakashi Gaiden and the events of the night Naruto was born.

Also, from the [talk page of Obito Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Obito_Uchiha) on Naruto wiki

> Obito-Kakashi timeline is based on the anime mostly and pre-chapter 599 manga/databook stuff. Kakashi graduated the academy as 5 years old, Rin and Obito as 9. Obito is 3 years 7 months older from Kakashi. They all took the same Chunin Exam, with Kakashi having managed to become a Chunin in it at the age of 6, while Obito age 10 failed. Obito trainer hard, took the next exams and became a Chunin at 11. Obito got crushed by boulders as 13 years old, that means Kakashi was 9-10 at the latest in the Gaiden. Kakashi is now 31 so Obito died as 34.

As for the youngest Jonin part, no one really knows how many official Jonin are there. If I remember correctly, Itachi wasn't officially declared as a Jonin. He got into the Anbu after he became a Chunin. So Kakashi **might** be the youngest Jonin. There is no definitive answer.

---

Edit (courtesy of [@Merrice Henderson](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/38125/merrice-henderson)):

There is evidence that Kakashi made Jonin the same year that Obito and Rin made Chunin. This is an exert from Obito's wikia page:

> Eager for Rin's attention, Obito trained relentlessly, eventually rising to the rank of chūnin himself. His excitement was short-lived as Kakashi soon afterwards became a jōnin, once again earning Rin's praise and Obito's resentment."

So, Obito was confirmed 11 when he became Chunin. If we go based on the theory that Kakashi is 4 years younger (which I am more inclined to believe), then he was 7 when he made Jonin. That would effectively make him the youngest Jonin of all time. If Kakashi was the same age as Obito and Rin, there are a few years that need to be accounted for, like:

- "Who was he teamed with after graduation while Obito and Rin were still in the academy?"
- "What happened to Kakashi's other teammates, or was he on hiatus for that time?"

Answer (score 4):

After some web digging, I found the exact chapter which mentions about Kakashi's Jounin promotion. It is in [the manga chapter 239](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Day_of_Departure!!_(volume)).

Below are some relevant pages from the manga chapters:

[image]
[image]

With this new finding, can we say that Kakashi became a Jounin at the age of 9, given the fact that he was [4 years younger](http://www.narutoforums.com/showthread.php?t=855357) than Obito, and Obito was 13 in [Kakashi Gaiden](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha). Thus, we can confirm that this [website](http://www.narutohq.com/hatake-kakashi.php) and the Yahoo answer which say that Kakashi became a Jounin at the age of 13 are wrong.

About the youngest Jounin, it is still a mystery.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Kakashi was already a Jonin when he was 13. I don't want to spoil you, but there is an episode where his former teammates gave him presents for his promotion to Jonin.
However, he may not be the youngest Jonin, because Itachi Uchiha became Chunin when he was 10, and at 13, he was already the leader of an Anbu unit. So he might have become Jonin somewhere between the age of 10 and 13, which means he was younger than Kakashi when he became one.

Comment: But, Nowhere its mentioned that Itachi became Jonin. And, there's no reference that only Jonin could become Anbu member/captain.

Comment: That's why I said that he "might" bot be the youngest jonin. It's just a specilation.

Answer (score 2):

I think Kakashi was **10 years** old when he became a jonin because there was a couple of evidence for example one is when Minato is talking Obito the story of how Kakashi's dad died. Minato specifically said "Five years ago".Then in other chapter or on the anime there is one episode mostly about Obito, but in one scene he tells his grandma he is **five years old**, that means Kakashi should be around his age. Mostly because they look the same age. Then later on Kakashi's dad kills himself. Just leaving Kakashi being five or maybe six years old. So if you don't know your math five plus five is ten.
Also I don't think Obito and Rin are about 4 years older than Kakashi because they were in the same class in the beginning and they did not look any older. Also if they were older, when it should the flash backs when they were in the Academy, they would of looked really similar to what they looked like in Kakashi Gaiden.

Episodes 119 and 120 are the episodes of Team Minato (Minato, Kakashi, Obito, and Rin) going to destroy Kannabi Bridge. In episode 119 Minato tells the story about why Kakashi was the way he was. In episode 415 Obito tells his grandma he is 5 years old. Later on in that same episode he goes with Rin to a Youth Ninjutsu Competition. There Kakashi, Obito, and Rin look exactly the same age. But if I'm wrong and Obito and Rin are about 4 years older than Kakashi, why was Kakashi not one year old. But sorry I'm putting to much of my opinions. On episode 119, around 13 minutes and 24 seconds Minato says “Five years ago” when he is going to tell the story about Kakashi, so you can check that out on the link below. Also, on Obito's wiki page it says he is exactly Kakashi's age in Naruto Shippuden.

Sources:

- [Episode 119](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-119-kakashi-chronicles-a-boys-life-on-the-battlefield-part-1-530552)
- [Episode 415](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-415-the-two-mangekyo-677361)
- [Obito Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha)

Answer (score 0):

Itachi was never a jōnin. He entered ANBU as a chūnin. ANBU is chūnin and above, not just jōnin.
While Itachi was an S-rank nuke-nin, and of jōnin level ability, he was never officially made a jōnin.
Imagine how that would look in the clan massacre cover up. 
"Oh, look, that ninja the leaf village just promoted to jōnin butchered his entire family bar one and defected! Their highest level ninja aren't even loyal!"
Yeah. Danzō Shimura may be an asshole, but he isn't that stupid.

Kakashi entered the academy with Rin and Obito but graduated at 5, meaning he was obviously moved class.
He became Minato's apprentice and would likely have taken the chūnin exams (which he passed at 6) with a team who had lost a member. (Team rotation).
It does not mention the specific age that Kakashi became a jōnin but he does say that "by Naruto's age" he was already a jōnin, meaning he was definitely younger than 13.

Answer (score 0):

Kakashi became Jounin at the age of 13, but if Kakashi is 4 years younger than both Obito and Rin, how could Obito attacked Konoha at the age of 15?! Also, Obito didn't attack Konoha after almost dying, there was a 2 year gap.

So, long story short, Kakashi and Obito are of same age.

Comment: Can you provide canon references to support your statement, `Kakashi became Jounin at the age of 13`?

Answer (score 0):

SPOILERS BELOW.

Kakashi was in anbu for the span of 10 years (in the anime) 
 This was after Rin died when he was fourteen (he was promoted to jounin at 13 like the person above said the same year Obito died), a year after Obito's death. Minato wanted to keep Kakashi closer to him after Rin died.

In the Anbu filler side stories,four years pass when he meets Tenzo and he's already Captain of Team Ro by then. This puts him at 18. Four years because Hiruzen BSs the reason Yamato be transferred out of Root by saying,"the kyubi Jinchuriki is already 4 years old and we'll need the wood release user to control the kyubi if we need it" and since Kakashi made anbu the same year Minato died and Naruto was born four years had passed since then putting him at 17 or 18 when he made Captain. So far all together it adds up to 6 years. Itachi joins anbu at 10 (In the anime idk about the manga but the anime sub has a passing comment from Yamato about 10 years being the youngest anbu ever) and was made captain of his own team by 13. This is another 3 years. 6+3=9.

He stays one more year (That's 10 years in Anbu) until he's forcibly demoted because his friends are concerned for his mental health. The first batch of students Kakashi (he should be 24) fails for not grasping teamwork.

The second year (he should be 25- Neji Ten Ten and Lee graduate this year since they graduated one year ahead of Team Seven and train under Gai)he fails another team.

Right around the time a third set of his students: Sakura, Sasuke and Naruto graduate he's 26 which adds up to The Naruto Wikia page and the three year timeskip into Shippuden when wikia says he starts off as 29

Please correct me if I'm wrong ahaha or if my math went stupid somewhere. I was trying to figure this out too by braindumping

Answer (score 0):

According to the Naruto online, from bandai ingame quiz the correct awnser is 12. 
It says thats the official game and lots of the stuff is correct but something are not totaly correct and this one falls in that catogory