# Why does Obito look like an adult during the Kyuubi attack on Konoha?

Tags: naruto

In the series, it is stated that Kakashi was 26 when he became the leader of Naruto's squad. So following that, he was 14 when the Kyuubi attacked the village. Seeing that Obito was the same age as Kakashi, he should be 14 but he didn't look like it. How old was Obito at that time? It shows him as an grown up, adult man. Is this because of Zetsu covering him or is he just older than Kakashi?

This is not a question directly about the age of Obito but also why he looked older. In my understanding Kakashi and Obito are about the same age. I don't care when Kakashi became a Jounin because that is not relevant to this question.

Comment: You can't judge someone's age by looking at their height.He could of just had a massive growth spurt in the past year before he attacked konoha.Obito and kakashi are the same age.Obito's just a few months older.But kakashi is just a short kid who acts older than obito.

Comment: I can't believe people doesn't know why. He was wearing white zetsu which makes him look bigger. Go read the manga!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in age between Obito and Kakashi has been explained in this [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19385/at-what-age-did-kakashi-hatake-become-a-jounin/19400#19400).

From [this thread on narutoforums](http://www.narutoforums.com/showthread.php?t=855357) (emphasis mine):

> It is impossible for both Kakashi and Obito to have been 13 during the Kakashi Gaiden, because there is at least a confirmed **4 year age difference** between Kakashi and Obito when they were confirmed to both be Genin teammates during the Chuunin Exams. They entered the academy the same time, and they all graduated the academy together as teammates. Kakashi was at least 4 years younger than both of his teammates at all times. There is **no** possible way that Kakashi was a 13 year old Jonin during the Kakashi Gaiden.

Since Kakashi is younger than Obito, obviously Obito will look older.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't completely right. We have clearly seen Kakashi's backstory in the anime. There we see that Obito and Kakashi many times together, especially at Kannabi bridge. They both appear to be of the same height. Kakashi was about 12-13 at that time. If Obito was actually 4 years older than him, then he should have been taller than him. I myself don't know the answer, but I know that the hypothesis given by **Ero Sennin** isn't completely right.

Comment: It is quite unclear how you can judge a character's age just by looking at their height. Height doesn't necessarily correlate with age. And analysing height alone, you can't just declare an answer.I derived my answer using the facts provided from the series. If you can pinpoint which of it is incorrect, I'll be happy to correct or withdraw my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a guess but the looks could have been different because of the zetsu thingy attached to obitos body. Maybe he made the zetsu part appear more adult like to misguide any possible connection any of his former friends may find in his behavior if he ran into them. Judging by how long he observed kushinas pregnancy and waited for the opportunity , it is possible that he considered more than several scenarios of the attack. but again it is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems like that could be true and considering he became chuunin and jounin at such a young might mean that. But from my understanding Kakashi must of just been a really strong and smart ninja. But considering that Rin, Obito and Kakashi were in the academy at the same time and how Kakashi easily knew the rules from the top of his head might just means he is the same age but just smarter.

Its the same with Sasuke. Anyone can say his age is 4 years younger than Naruto but it would not add up. I just think that Kakashi is the same age, short, and may just talk smack about Obito.

He could very well be 4 years younger but there's just not enough evidence to support that. Although its very smart to assume that he is younger because just because they are in the same cell does not mean they are the same age.